# How to decode bytes in GB18030 correctly

Tags: python, java, character-encoding

Recently, I am studying [GB 18030](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GB_18030), and found that some characters cannot encoded/decoded correctly when they are mapped to the *private user area* (PUA). For example, according to the specification of GB 18030, this is *A6* double-byte region:

[image]

Most characters' encoding/decoding are expected:

```py
ch = b'\xA6\F5'
print(ch.decode('gb18030')) #  ︴
```

But some are not:

```py
ch = b'\xA6\xDA'
print(ch.decode('gb18030')) # , but it should be︒
```

I also tested in Java, and the results are the same. It seems that if the characters are mapped to PUA, neither Java nor Python can decode them correctly. Is it related to the specific language/library implementation?

Comment: I think those encodings are implemented differently in different platforms. Take `0xA6DA` for example. Python fails to decode it using `GBK`, while Java is able to do so.

Comment: Your `` is indeed the Unicode character U+E78E, though, so this is technically "correctly decoded", but the system fonts don't have data for it (and it can basically be used for different things depending on the font used).
You thought it should be `︒`, but that is U+FE12.

Comment: @qrsngky So, I need to a **compatible** font in order to use GB18030/GBK, right?

Comment: "It seems that if the characters are mapped to PUA, neither Java nor Python can decode them correctly." - well, yes; that's what it means to map something to PUA (a Private Use Area) - the interpretation of the code point is up to the implementation, and not specified by Unicode. Your Python and Java code is applying the encoding properly; the encoding just doesn't actually give code points that correspond to valid glyphs in modern Unicode. You can see this in the table on the Wikipedia page you cited.

Comment: Or, you can manually replace those PUA characters with similar characters that form part of standard Unicode. (e.g. `U+E78E` with `U+FE12`, as shown in the Wikipedia table)

Comment: @qrsngky it is [more complicated than that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Not sure what your concern is, when OP is only concerned about a small part of PUA and is not trying to mix with PUA characters obtained from other sources

Comment: Python's `gb18030` codec is actually `gb18030-2005` instead of `gb18030-2022` according to [the table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GB_18030#History) (further down in that section), based on the conversion of byte sequence `A6 DA` to `U+E78E` as per that table.

Comment: I wonder what those empty cells in the table (mapping to `E785` to `E78C` and `E797` to `E79F`) are supposed to represent. Spaces of different widths?

Comment: @qrsngky These empty cells are not assigned to characters yet, and they are maybe used for future extensions.