# Why do Python and Java behave differently when decoding GBK

Tags: python, java, unicode, character-encoding

This question is related to [How to decode bytes in GB18030 correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76232910/).

I would like to decode an array of bytes which are encoded with [GBK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GBK_(character_encoding)), but found that Python and Java behave differently sometimes.

```py
ch = b'\xA6\xDA'
print(ch.decode('gbk'))
```

It raises an error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0xa6 in position 0: illegal multibyte sequence

Java is able to decode it.

```java
byte[] data = {(byte) 0xA6, (byte) 0xDA};
String s = new String(data, Charset.forName("GBK"));
System.out.println(s);
```

It seems that Python and Java adopt different implementations for `GBK`, right?

Comment: Does it work if you replace gbk (gb16500) with gb18030?

Comment: @Corralien Yes. Both Java and Python work if I use GB18030.

Comment: [Related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883573/encoding-error-in-python-with-chinese-characters/) - Moreover, look at [CP936](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_936_(Microsoft_Windows)), which is aliased to `gbk` in Python (check result of `b'\xa6\xda'.decode('cp936')`), which may be a source of confusion. On top of that, quoting wikipedia, "most modern-day Windows-based software products mean partial support for GBK via Windows-936 when they use the term "GB 2312" as a character encoding option", so my original hunch that Python maps GBK to GB 2312 may be correct.

Comment: That all being said, `/bin/echo -e '\xa6\xda' | iconv -f gbk -t utf8` also report `illegal input sequence at position 0`, likewise if `gbk` is substituted for `gb2312` or `gb13000` - thus I am pretty sure `a6` is out of range of those earlier standards and only `gb18030` actually supports `a6`, and `gbk` in Java may in fact refer to the later standard.

Comment: If you really want to use `gbk` encoding, you can use `errors='ignore'` for characters outside the valid range: `print(ch.decode('gbk', errors='ignore'))`

Comment: It's complicated. In python codecs module gbk means microsoft's cp936. IANA uses them as aliases. CP936 is a superset of what isreferred to asGBK which in turn is a superset of GB 2312. Then there is GBK 1.0 another extension. I am not sure which Java using but Python's documentation indicates gbk is Windows Code page 936.

Comment: @Andj I have figured it out by checking out both OpenJDK's and CPython's source code.

Comment: @chenzhongpu, all good then. Interestingly, web standards take a different view. On the web, GBK is aliased to GB 2312. And GBK uses the gb18030 decoder and encoder with a GBK flag. More of an issue if you are scraping content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems that Python and Java adopt different implementations for GBK, right?

Yes. GBK is a ambiguous encoding to some extent, and thus different platforms may adopt different implementations.

As for Python (CPython here), the mapping between GBK to Unicode is defined in [mappings_cn.h](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/cjkcodecs/mappings_cn.h), which is a *strict* implementation of [CP936](https://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WINDOWS/CP936.TXT), where some characters (such as `0xA6DA`) in non-Chinese regions are not defined.

In the contrast, GBK in Java (OpenJDK 17 here), in fact, is an *extended* CP936 where [some extra non-Chinese characters are included](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17/blob/4afbcaf55383ec2f5da53282a1547bac3d099e9d/make/data/charsetmapping/GBK.map#L7322) in order to follow GB18030/MS936. For example, `0xA6DA` is mapped to Unicode `U+E78E` (although it is a private-user-area one).